# jQuery addClass only affecting current item

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, fadeout, addclass

I use this code to make a slider function.

```
$(function() {
$(".slider").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > 200) {
            $(".well").fadeOut(500, function(){
            $( ".well" ).delay(1000).addClass( "disappear" );
            $( ".showup" ).delay(500).removeClass( "disappear" );
            });
        } else {
            // $("h2 span").css("opacity", 100 - (ui.position.left / 5))
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 201) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0
            })
        }
    }
});

$('.slider')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = event.target;
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    curX = touch.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 40;
    if(curX <= 0) return;
    if(curX > 200){
        $('.well').fadeOut();
        $(".well").addClass( "disappear" );
        $('.well').add('<h2>Erbjudandet använt</h2>');
    }
    el.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + curX + 'px)'; 
}, false);

$('.slider')[0].addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {  
    this.style.webkitTransition = '-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in';
    this.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { this.style.webkitTransition = 'none'; }, false );
    this.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(0px)';
}, false);

});
```

Here is my HTML for displaying the slider:

```
return  "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.infid.se/wp-content/themes/simplemarket/anvandstyle.css'>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://www.infid.se/wp-content/themes/simplemarket/slidetounlock.js'></script>
<div id='page-wrap'>
    <div class='showup disappear'><h2>Erbjudande använt</h2></div>
        <div class='well'>
            <h2><strong class='slider'></strong> <span>Använd erbjudande</span></h2>
        </div>
</div>";
```

The problem here is that I have about 100 of these sliders, and when slider is activated(The "disappear" class makes it disappear, and the h2 is added on), all of them disappears. Is there a way to make the "disappear" class only affect the current item?

Comment: Sure, here is the CSS for the .disappear class:

.disappear:before {
  content: "<h2 style='color:#101010;'>Erbjudande använt</h2>";
}

.disappear{
display:none;
}

The .showup CSS is just basic:

.showup {padding: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;border: 2px solid #0b98f2;overflow: hidden;-webkit-user-select: none;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the element relative to the current slider so change.

```
    $('.well').fadeOut();
    $(".well").addClass( "disappear" );
    $('.well').add('<h2>Erbjudandet använt</h2>');
```

to

```
    $well = $(this).closest('.well');  //Select only the respective well element.
    $well.fadeOut();
    $well.addClass( "disappear" );
    $well.add('<h2>Erbjudandet använt</h2>');
    .....
    $well.prev(".showup").delay(500).removeClass( "disappear" );
```

Similarly you can change this in other events as applicable.

```
$(".slider").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > 200) {
            var $well  = $(this).closest('.well');
            $well.fadeOut(500, function(){
            $well.delay(1000).addClass( "disappear" );
            $well.prev(".showup").delay(500).removeClass( "disappear" );
            });
        } else {
            // $("h2 span").css("opacity", 100 - (ui.position.left / 5))
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 201) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0
            })
        }
    }
});

$('.slider')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = event.target;
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    curX = touch.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 40;
    if(curX <= 0) return;
    if(curX > 200){
         var $well  = $(this).closest('.well');
        $well.fadeOut();
        $well.addClass( "disappear" );
        $well.add('<h2>Erbjudandet använt</h2>');
    }
    el.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + curX + 'px)'; 
}, false);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDhD4/)**

Comment: This seems to be the right answer in a logical sense, however it does not seem to work for this particular instance. If it would help, an active page with 4 sliders can be found here:

http://infid.se/asd

Comment: @JohannesPersson Check the Demo provided. This should be enough to take you the right way...

Comment: @JohannesPersson and the page you have shown doesn't have the updated code also provide a fiddle in this case to demonstrate the issue. and here is a demo with your html code.. http://jsfiddle.net/ua9Qr/2/show/

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. My update response time is really slow. The demo worked though, so hopefully this will work without trouble once it updates.